# RAZOR- How to get the first SELECTED OPTION

Tags: html, razor

I am currently working on RAZOR project and I have this dynamic HTML SELECT OPTIONS.

```
var selected="selected";

<select name="Ctry" id="Ctry" required>
            <option   @if (item.p2kValue.ToString().IsEmpty() || item.p2kValue.ToString().Replace(" ", "") == "")
                            { @selected; }></option>
    @foreach (var ritem in Model.RItems)
        {
            <option value="@ritem.ReasonCode" @if (ritem.ReasonCode.Contains(item.p2kValue.Replace(" ", "")))
                                                        { @selected; } >  @ritem.ReasonDesc</option>
        }
</select>
```

Everything works fine. When there is an existing data, it can set that as the default selected option. But what I am having a trouble with is when there is no data retrived, the default should be Blank which is the first option. But my code gets the last option. Maybe because there are also SELECTED attribute but it is conditional.I tried to put the Blank option to the last which apprently work but the REQUIRED attribute in SELECT does not work.

So to make the question simple, how can I set the Blank option (first option) as the default when there is no data retrieved while there are conditional SELECTED attributes in other options.

Please help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For dropdownlist in html5 you can add a attribute tag in select and the option (which denote to "No option selected") must have empty string as value.

This way you can force the user to select the option before proceed.